# Apache Common CLI: How to add arguments?

Tags: java, apache-commons

I am using the Common CLI for a personal project. One thing I didn't find from the documentation is that how to enforce a certain argument to present.

To clarify my question, can I define the different between argument and option, the command:

```
    mycommand file.txt -b 2

mycommand is the command, 
file.txt is the argument
-b 2 is the option where 2 is the option value
```

With Common CLI, I can add -b 2 as an option like this:

```
    options.addOption( "b", true, "Some message" );
```

And parse the arguments using:

```
CommandLineParser commandParser = new GnuParser();
CommandLine result = commandParser.parse(options, args)
```

but how can I specify file.txt is also required?

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT:  I didn't realize you meant make the target (not an option) to be required.

If you use the full parse method`CommandLineParser.parse(Options, String[], boolean)` with the optional flag set to false, then the parser will skip over unknown arguments.

You can later retrieve them by the method `getArgs()` which returns a String[]

You can then go through those Strings to make sure there is a string called file.txt

```
Options options = new Options();

options.addOption("b", true, "some message");

String[] myArgs = new String[]{"-b","2", "file.txt"};
CommandLineParser commandParser = new GnuParser();

CommandLine commandline = commandParser.parse(options, myArgs, false);

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(commandline.getArgs()));
```

Will print `[file.txt]` to the screen.

so you add an extra check to search through that array to find any required targets:

```
boolean found=false;
for(String unparsedTargets : commandline.getArgs()){
    if("file.txt".equals(unparsedTargets)){
        found =true;
    }
}
if(!found){
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("must provide a file.txt");
}
```

I agree it's messy but I don't think CLI provides a clean way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

No, is not possible with current API, but I think you can extends GnuParser with your own implementation of `Parser.parse()` if mandatory parameter name EVER file.txt.
Else, if file name can change, you can override `Parser.processArgs()` (for not Option args, your filename, I mean) and `Parser.processOption()` (to set a flag indicates you found a valid Option): if you enter in `Parser.processArgs()` when flag is set you found an invalid unnamed arg)

```
public class MyGnuParser extends GnuParser {

    private int optionIndex;
    private String filename;

    public MyGnuParser() {
        this.optionIndex = 0;
        this.filename = null;
    }

public CommandLine parse(Options options, String[] arguments, Properties properties) throws ParseException {
       CommandLine cmdLine = super.parse(options, arguments, properties, false);
       if(this.filename == null) throw new ParseException(Missing mandatory filename argument);
    }

    @Override
    public void processArgs(Option opt, ListIterator iter) throws ParseException {
      super.processArgs(opt, item);
      ++this.optionIndex;
    }

    @Override
    protected void processOption(final String arg, final ListIterator iter) throws    ParseException {
      if(this.optionIndex > 0) {
        throw new ParseException(non-opt arg must be the first);
      }
      if(this.filename != null) {
        throw new ParseException(non-opt invalid argument);
      }
      this.filename = arg;
      ++this.optionIndex;
    }
}

MyGnuParser p = new MyGnuParser();
CommandLine cmdLine = p.parse(options, args, properties);
```

and in `p.filename` (or `cmdLine.getArgs[0]`) you can get filename.

It's not intuitive, but with CLI API I don't known any other way